# Determining the integral of $f(z)\, dz$ and expressing the answer in terms of residue.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Suppose that $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, ±i\} → \mathbb{C}$ is the rational function
$$f(z) = {a_{−3}\over z^3} −{a_{−2}\over z^2}+{a_{−1}\over z}+ a_0 + za_1 +{z\over (z^2+1)}.$$
Let $Γ$ denote the positively oriented circle of radius $1/2$
about the origin. Determine the integral of $f(z)$ and express your answer in terms of $\mathrm{Res}(f; 0)$, the residue for $f$ at the pole $z_0 = 0$.

So far: 
I found that $Γ(t)=(1/2)e^{it}$.  I also found that the partial fractions of $z\over (z^2+1)$ are $1\over 2(z+i)$ + $1\over 2(z-i)$ and therefore there are poles at $0,i,-i$.

Because only the pole $0$ is in or on the contour, the integral of $z\over(z^2+1)$ = $0$.  Furthermore because $a_0 + za_1$ is entire, this integral is also zero. I'm now stuck with how to finish the problem. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $n \ne -1$, then
\begin{align}
\int_\Gamma z^n dz &= \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n e^{in t} \frac{1}{2}ie^{it}dt\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}i\left[\frac{1}{i(n+1)}e^{i(n+1)t}\right]_0^{2\pi}\\
&=0.
\end{align}
Then only $\frac{a_{-1}}{z}$ term remains.